# Typescript object of mapped types

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can accept an object whose properties are mapped by their `type` key. For example:

```
const fieldProps = useFormField({ type: 'date', minDate: new Date() }) // 
const fieldProps = useFormField({ type: 'email', minDate: new Date() }) // ❌ no minDate on email types
```

This function (`useFormField`) needs to use the incoming `type` property to determine the correct input, as well as the correct return value and some properties for a state manager inside it. The config, state and return values have only some overlap. This function is not the problem and is working fine so far.

The problem is another function (`useForm`) that is essentially a scaled version of `useFormField`. It expects an object of field configs (along with other possible options) and needs to infer the correct config values, return values and state shape based on the `type` property of each passed field.

```
const { fields } = useForm({
  fields: {
    date: { type: 'date', minDate: new Date().toISOString() },
    name: { type: 'text' },
    multiselect: { type: 'multiselect' },
  },
  onSubmit: () => {}
})
```

[Here is a ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=132&ssc=1&pln=138&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QGLAgGwBMAFKAewAcMAeAFWQF5kMwpQBzAPmQG8AoZMkRhgANwgB%20AFzIARmTL4IcEAG4ByAORw2cALShRcfMEKbpchUpXrBhYBjiylhC-MXK1G6OSgWWbCDstsgAFqaEECBuVp4hpjIBHCFkIKj4AK5QMgAUAJSM3KJkpikgAMKhKuwQuQUMRSWEZdhkCBkYdYXIxaUaUBAAjhnAA64y7tZegmBkGQihEOOWHjYaRpm1yLTqAL7qfGAAnhQo6Fi4BITlqTDA7HSMzKwc3Ez8guGEkdETsWuCQQDYajJYxVbTQHHU6JF5BEIbUxwWZ%20GQANWMSJR2BAdE4COMGUkMh2fH2fD4EAAHhQyFAwMgohkALbIYhkFjGG6RAAybWMKA%20yAAqgBlJ6aMWaAA0GnKAEEJQqZWSKdCUOzOfhuRBSJQME8eMh8PylBZNWAuWReaaUOTDicUAARZG68hUQ0aZyIADWczALsgGAs8qgUDgR2oSSC%20I0zLgVMDxOegWCcdASf8cLT9vVyAAcizoMAEHqPe84wmLCAWbJoCFmaBq7X6xoKAM7lSs6mQhgMjBO93kmSDtTafTkHmMSZCMi6TjHkwVEc3sgcu39TJzjg8EQbiA7g9aJx6txo2mHadkK0oMzLkRp0SDRXBAsIAgffIqX8ISE3x%20TBYWFUwAbQAXQbDJ8BELAlAQMBgI4cC9gOPN72uW57mfXgNH-T8yG-NBMB3K590PagbzvXdCEfCAMBAzQ8K-TQwNjV9FgAhwEKIi5qLI%204KLpKirlo%20jGI4n1ALAFi2OQWdIC3Yj0P49hkAAMmQJMywwEIIHjYB8EU3jSMwtNBGZVIICOIySL3Uz1ILIs2FLd0dLjKCYIId9uO3ZTTME290NEhjmQ8hwvPgmSQhrZk62yHjbIwg97gcwtmWLFz9RCChQksmy-OSszkFpLUdXyvj7I0i0rUibSQnDewyHKkzCt7CKfKUirWo0SAqQ64y7O63NHWvajtM9dj33wwjfLG1yAuEh9CTohimIIqLcIkqTmqIbSFqC5axLwqSNrsV0dpIVyHK01yG0s6yEvQ8aNLSjK6vc6Dwrg-rEr2yiDs2MTQs%202DvNO5AYrii7nsc9LnPewQSstbVrS2Warhh6qUdq27VUpGk6QZNDqIAaSsp4fSssgYFGlrDwwCkx0JycRoAJToxRxEIAr6cealIBAQgDXPVd6H5qIheQSmjmp2nBvp5AJDlpL6ZA2gwOQC6VMZgmJzzdmME5pYAaJPm%20ol4Xs1FxlzcFg1pdl-7qNExXryEk2VvVzWUw4HXxyJtmOfwLmnvmsXbclkWnnDgXJYdmmnZEw7XcTpbAbVjXEKCP3mbQoSAAkFB9UP9TN2PLdTVcjXVElkF2ByDaN7mut549R11gOr2FC53eog3aRALAy4tn2Y2jm3y6lqmE7m-UU9nqgM%2099HdtxvgAHp14hiAlgNWZkBqInFmQNh2FCBl0LJo4emWycyAPiAj5QU-z%20QUAEDIRsgmK1yN63zBkAAHcCD4CEHvY%20L8GQDDAFkEAP99T439sgGAGQQDwWAKkZAHQcC9yuMPO2ysr6cByG2VyMhKKFzIMXBeNBjyynYtUCAToIBUBkMucCTxwJ8DyDIbuODAp9zogPIex4cKCE3sgAAVJIycx9pZrloAUBwQh8CGywVgQgd94GiFMCgMAED7ivw2ESFmV595wGeK6ZA8YQBwBqFAN%20cDFgDH6I-WBvBdh4wkdI5guUoKaNADAaAsiUAfzDN5ZAH9CrwNOPSPABpZDEU0ZggABuqFJfAoksGKhyZGJdyzqP4YtQgORq6OhkJoeSEAZTWIzOdbegDNKunyAAOlmAASVFAAeVFNmfIdc8iZNSNkuAFlUFgHydhbBqcSllJhFoSG0AalfxkAABgGUMweDJ36f1%20ldJg0zcFEFKaYrYmgLIgCsss0AayNlZIZLY9KkyniHIEVcE5NctC9WktKWpIAkwyEuY0pMrSOndN6amfpuwCgSMADLkmzsnA08t9caBye5vOOXMs5SKvpgw2X-KRMiMB%20KIFLEAZBGn6NCXSAY8ET5uKgHAjcsSRB0TkEk5AmD1R8BQWgkQmCcXGIgDkIVWd2DgQKDwTxgrlo5BxaDeC2kWlCsGTKzYORHl7P1Mq5agyCXynghkYwjiKAZAZJQflg9kF0hCcg1B6DMGgGQMMOilqCV5j4ZRVFOEJGAhUSaQB7SQCIkIKKDIshGwYAwBg34KwpjqF9YCO4VxOg%20q3n6v1IFpZirAuQguRdJkJvTYCckibxFb30co4wajLm7y0T6cllLj5RMPKcve98wm0rAPga%20gTgmckgL4uApwCV%20uTUQXprp2aEHmNACw-SGgeOQAAHwhlBfARaM2pDDRG4A3EF2ND6BIzx7rwgGmUVS%20Bzg9IEp8cSuYpK6xCGvVo%20MFAhBwLILIAAVhEmANrx2aJbVhOQ180mOgyd4olJLNHVvvk%20pwShX3Do-Zyn9ETZbQPcUKhJYH0k8vtZawplF8GSyFIIECJNHFTxljTdWJJKMa3FgQrF5DSbk3rkrChBaaF0EYwxdUMll6dTpvcMkxDmWpqNIB1N9BoUyGk9RWTdcxGAiw4y3gyClMKfrp4k9UHfEPqAzS7yPbHFBIccy6ArKEkcq5Y6BFDJFMppU2ioppSNAyYUxoM6ClNOfMqa6a5-z6lAqaZAUFZBOk9L6QUXY9DASaoU6cip3zgsAoaeF4VeQ2lRfBbFuuvyJH3v8XIFAPg6Q%20esWFBV3FWNaHle1GpoqtCaEK8gYrMGyuMjDJVwQem9UGZK6Sztpne0HmCeppl7prPxPZRozlcDuVqqJDkGTLTGvfR1ZsGFW9huaKfaN%20CfAVvCvW5q7bRJduGdK0%20irUAgA) with all the essential code to reproduce this. I am not sure on the best/simplest approach for this setup.

I am not sure how I can get the `type` from each item in the fields object as a value I can pass like a generic, since it needs different input + return values.

I've tried discriminated union, based on the approach shown by @jcalz in the comments, but without success. It seems too complex to be solved with discriminated unions, but I could just be missing something and overcomplicating things. Any help you could give would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you get that code to be a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  It would be a lot easier to come up with a solution without having to figure out what, say, `BaseFormFieldProps` is, or without renaming it out of the way.

Comment: Good call. Working on it.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCbIN4BQyxyYAngA4QBcyAzmFKAOYDcRJctDTIbHxAEa0QAVwC2g6OwC+BUJFiIUqAParkEAB6QQ2Omgw58A0pRrIARDHWX2JZDdXdGLWfPDR4SZACE4UJo6EHoG6Fi4hA7kVLSWggF2pglQLrz8cjEoANIgqgDuIOHGALxo6sgAPn4B7AQwoiAIYMCqII4APAAqQbr6+MgA2tnIoMgA1hBkqjDIXQC6tF3D870h-Xhmsci5BUVG2IMA5FlHqzLIAPw7eYXFuLT3yDIAfAAUYEsAlANy9W9RTi0TZZOJOSwAGmQXCskOQwmQAEYoU44gALKaWZ5QgD0OOQqnGcDIyWBWws8USUJhljhCOR8ICcWmoixMlx+MJxNMCDJoKsCQAXnCaXTaIjscg8QSiSSHNg+eYwbZqXExUjJdLoFBVFAoRQdRRHBVxMA6HQWKYLCClQK4MLVbCofSUep0Zj2VL8drdVDGtoqM0ILgnMgDaoKAQZF8CEA) work for you?

Comment: It's the need to support unknown fields that makes it complicated; otherwise your fields would just be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

Comment: @jcalz you're spot on

Comment: If my code above works for you then I'll write it up as an answer; otherwise elaborate on the problem and I'll try to account for it.

Comment: That might. Trying it out now, will let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216908/discussion-between-shadymoses-and-jcalz).